# How to undo or remove a keep offset on a bone?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I want to remove an offset I created for a bone but don't know how to remove it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the child bone, Use shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> then pick the option that suits better your situation.